# insert every 3 element from object to a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

sorry if the title is messy, I didn't know how to phrase it right,
but it will be easier to show.

I'm using React JS, and I'm getting this object from my database:

```
{
id1: "1",
name1: "Jon",
image1: {url: "...."},

id2: "2",
name2: "Ron",
image2: {url: "...." , height: "10"},

id3: "2",
name3: "Jess",
image3: {url: "...." , height: "10"},
...
}
```

and so on,
all the fields are on their own in the object,
but I need that it would be an array (or object, I can map it through Object.keys..)
and every 3 fields (name, id, image) will be in the same object,
so I can map it to use with my component,

this is the example output that I am struggling to make:

```
[
{ name1:"Jon", id1:"1", image1: { url:"....", height:"10" } },

{ name2:"Ron", id2:"2", image2: { url:"....", height:"10" } },

{ name3:"Jess", id3:"3", image3: { url:"....", height:"10" } },
]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if each item in the array had properties named name/id/image?

Comment: You have to iterate over all the keys of the object looking for the key plus the index. Try a loop over Object.keys and repost if you can't figure it out. A question should at least show an attempt otherwise we can't know which part your having difficulty with.

Comment: The format of the data is strange, the backend should be fixed instead, if possible.

Comment: Please do not edit the question to say just "Thank you". You can edit your question and add that at the bottom. Without the question being present future readers will not know what the question was!

Answer (score 2):

I let you a piece of code who made that transformation

```
import React from 'react';

function Question24() {

  const initialObject = {
    id1: "1",
    name1: "Jon",
    image1: {url: "...."},

    id2: "2",
    name2: "Ron",
    image2: {url: "...." , height: "10"},

    id3: "2",
    name3: "Jess",
    image3: {url: "...." , height: "10"},
  };

  const result = [];
  let index = 1;
  while(Object.keys(initialObject).length) {
    const idKey = `id${index}`;
    const nameKey = `name${index}`;
    const imageKey = `image${index}`;
    const resObject = {};
    // I whould do ->  resObject.id = initialObject[idKey];
    resObject[idKey] = initialObject[idKey];
    delete initialObject[idKey];
    // I whould do ->  resObject.name = initialObject[idKey];
    resObject[nameKey] = initialObject[nameKey];
    delete initialObject[nameKey];
    // I whould do ->  resObject.image = initialObject[idKey];
    resObject[imageKey] = initialObject[imageKey];
    delete initialObject[imageKey];

    result.push(resObject);

    index++;
  }

  console.log("result: ", result);

  return (
    <div>Check the console</div>
  );
}

export default Question24;
```

I hope I've helped you :)

Comment: This is one way of doing it. You should try to avoid deleting properties from objects when possible. It's usually better to just return a new array to prevent pretty code from being affected

Comment: To avoid delete properties, the while conditicion could be: "while(initialObject[`id${index}`]) {"
Then, you can remove the delete lines.

I don't see any problem about deleting properties of an object that you shouldn't use after the parse function.

Comment: It's standard practice not to modify objects you didn't create, unless you're optimizing

Answer (score 0):

it is simple, just iterate through object keys and count every third step and put the last 3 entries into answers array.
although I am not sure if that model is the best practice to get data from database.

```js
obj = {
    id1: "1",
    name1: "Jon",
    image1: {url: "...."},
    
    id2: "2",
    name2: "Ron",
    image2: {url: "...." , height: "10"},
    
    id3: "2",
    name3: "Jess",
}

let answer = []
let temp = {}
let counter = 1;
for (let item in obj) {

    temp[item] = obj[item]
    if(counter == 3)
    {
        answer.push(temp);
        temp = {}
        counter = 1;
        continue;
    }
    counter ++;
}
// in case number of keys is not dividable by 3 and temp is not empty
answer.push(temp);
```

Comment: This expects the object properties to be in order which is ok if the literal object was created that way but it's hard to know that you can rely on other of properties in this case

Comment: You are right, I assumed they are in order and they need to partition them in 3 by 3 groups.
I stated above this kind of data modeling is not best practice and its not reliable

Comment: I don't know any database systems that retrieve data like this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
let object = {
    id1: "1",
    name1: "Jon",
    image1: {url: "...."},

    id2: "2",
    name2: "Ron",
    image2: {url: "...." , height: "10"},

    id3: "2",
    name3: "Jess",
    image3: {url: "...." , height: "10"},
};

const convertToArr = (object) => {
    let arr = [];

    for(let i=1; i<=Object.keys(object).length / 3; i++){
        let obj = {};
        obj.id = object[`id${i}`];
        obj.name = object[`name${i}`];
        obj.image = object[`image${i}`];
        arr.push(obj);
    }

    return arr;
}


console.log(convertToArr(object));
```